# Set color to Find/Replace dialog box in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am creating my own custom theme in VS code. I am not able to select the find/Replace dialog box for setting the color. So, the question is how can we set the color to the Find/Replace dialog box?

I have already set the color to the input box inside the Find/Replace dialog box.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try editing your settings.json

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "input.background": "#c21045"
},
```

I have gotten this

[image]

with :

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorWidget.background":"#ff0000",
},
```

[image]

For more information about vs code theme api:
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color

Comment: input box is inside the Find/Replace Dialog. I want to set color to Find/Replace dialog box.

Comment: ah, apologize, I think you mean "editorWidget.background", for more https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color

Comment: Thanks @jenloi This is what I want. Could you update your answer for future reference? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

That's a great idea of creating custom theme.
From my point of view, VS code uses common color for same category.

Vs code uses same color variable for all input box. here it is.

```
"input.background": "#000"
```

Here is the input color Property from which, this color is applied to `searchBox's input`.

**Note**: This Property will update all input's background color.

Comment: I have already set the color to input box. I want to know how can we set the background color to Find/Replace dialog box

Comment: okay, let me search about it. because I can't found any search specific proeprty from VS code's code